# How click on textview will open spinner android

Tags: android, textview, spinner

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Type"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="open_spinner"/>
```

---

### **string.xml**

```
<string-array name="type">
    <item>Male</item>
    <item>Female</item>
</string-array>
```

In xml file I already know to make `TextView` can click. But how I open like spinner when click on `TextView`?

Comment: You need to create a spinner in your layout file then set visibility to hidden or gone. Then on click of text view, just show it - as long as you populate the data in your activity or fragment

Comment: Depends on how it should be shown you could insert the spinner under your textview and toggle visibility, you could open another activity with the spinner, a fragment, dialog whatever you want

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but how on click of textview want open value list like spinner in activity file?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a spinner with visibility gone in your xml

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"
    />
```

inside your open_spinner method :

```
  Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);  

  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, youarrayofStrings);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

  spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: That makes the textview and the spinner both  on the screen